# In Visual Basic .NET, how can I list and call all class functions with a given custom attribute?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, delegates, custom-attributes

I have a Windows Forms / Visual Basic .NET application which basically acts as an editor. One of the functions it should provide its users with is the ability to run a set of rules on their current project and report any problems it finds. These rules will all be run by a BackgroundWorker object living in a form, so execution progress can be reported.

My strategy for implementing this is to give the form a bunch of private instance methods which take in the user's project data (contained in, say, a `ProjectData` object), run whatever check is needed at that step, and return an object containing displayable information about the test and whether it passed or failed. (Let's call this class `CheckResult` for discussion purposes). So, just to be clear, all of these methods would have a signature along the lines of:

```
Private Function SomeCheckToRun(data As ProjectData) As CheckResult
```

I *could* just define all these methods as usual and manually list them out one-by-one to be called in the BackgroundWorker's `DoWork` event handler, but that approach seems like it would get tedious for a potentially large number of checks. It would be nice if I could just define each method I want to run and have it decorated as such, so that a loop could automatically find each such method definition and run it.

What I'm thinking I would like to do instead is to define a custom attribute class used to indicate which instance methods are meant to be run as checks (maybe called `CheckToRunAttribute`), then use reflection somehow to get a list of all these methods currently implemented in the form and execute each one in sequence, perhaps by setting up a delegate to run for each one. The number of these methods in total, and how many have been executed so far, can be used by the BackgroundWorker to indicate overall progress.

So far, the structure of my code would look something like the following in my mind:

```
Private Sub MyBackgroundWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles MyBackgroundWorker.DoWork
    ' TODO: Get a list of all the <CheckToRun()> methods here,
    '       run each one in a loop, and report progress after each one.
End Sub

' Further down...

<CheckToRun()>
Private Function SomeCheckToRun(data As ProjectData) As CheckResult
    ' Check code in here.
End Function

<CheckToRun()>
Private Function AnotherCheckToRun(data As ProjectData) As CheckResult
    ' Check code in here.
End Function

<CheckToRun()>
Private Function YetAnotherCheckToRun(data As ProjectData) As CheckResult
    ' Check code in here.
End Function

' And so on...
```

This is not something I have much experience with doing though. I know about the [`Type.GetMethods()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb(v=vs.110).aspx) function, [how to write custom attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56(v=vs.110).aspx), and the [`Func(T, TResult)` delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx), but I'm not sure how to put it all together for what I want.

**tl;dr:** Given a class with multiple private instance functions following the same signature and all marked with the same custom attribute, how can I count how many there are and then run each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Reflection to list all the methods with your custom attribute. This is a Linq solution:

```
Dim methods = Me.GetType.GetMethods(Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)_
                      .Where(Function(m) m.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(CheckToRun), False)_
                      .Length > 0).ToArray()
```

And then run them like:

```
For Each method As Reflection.MethodInfo In methods
   method.Invoke(Me, New Object() {methodParams})
Next
```

Comment: Works like a charm! This will save me a ton of work. Thanks a ton!